# Lipschitz extensions preserving the convex hull of the range

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

We assume that $X$ is a metric space and that $A \subseteq X$ is a subset. Let $f : A \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a Lipschitz-continuous function with Lipschitz constant $L$.

By the Kirszbraun theorem, we can extend $f$ to the whole of $X$ without increasing the Lipschitz constant:
we let $F : X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be

$F(x) = \inf_{ a \in A } \Big\{\; f(a) + L \cdot d( a, x ) \;\Big\}$.

The Lipschitz constants of $f$ and $F$ are the same but the range of $F$ is generally larger than the range of $f$.

Can we construct an extension of $f$ to all of $X$ such that not only the Lipschitz constant but also the convex hull of the range remains the same.

Comment: Not always, take $X=[0,1]$, $A=\{0,1\}$, $f(x)=x$ on $A$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Thank you for pointing out that example. I have edited the question: the range is convex in my application, which rules out your example.

Comment: Still no. $X=[0,1]$, $A=[0,1)$, $f(x)=x$ on $A$.

Comment: The extension can be constructed so that the closure of convex hull of the range remains. That is about maximum one can achieve.

Comment: Btw, the quoted result is not Kirszbraun theorem (that deals with extending Hilbert-valued map defined on subsets of the Hilbert space).

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I realized the question is much simpler than I thought and I am okay with either closing it or moving it to Math.SE.

Comment: @PietroMajer: thank you for the comment. Interestingly, not only Wikipedia but also Enc. of Math. (https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Kirszbraun_theorem) suggest otherwise.

Comment: Not exactly: in Kirszbraun theorem the domain is always subset of a Hilbert space $H$. The co-domain is a Hilbert space (the same space $H$, with no loss of generality, or another one, in particular  the trivial case $\mathbb{R}$).